# Laravel converting html page to pdf or docx

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I have Ckeditor, inside what I put some text. At the end I have html code, what i must convert and put to pdf or docx files (better pdf).
Firsly I tried to use Dompdf, but because of I had cyrillic symbols in my text and they do not display correctly.

[image: Looks like this.]

Maby someone know how to do it? Help please.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

Package name is : mPDF

package : https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

documentation : https://mpdf.github.io/

to installing via composer : `composer require mpdf/mpdf`

Comment: this library also can add header image to every page of pdf file? or it just convert html to pdf without any options to adding something?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using **dompdf** with greek characters without having any problems.
You need to check the fonts provided with dompdf.

I load my own fonts using css in the html that is converted by dompdf.

I have also found this package to be useful ([laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)). It provides a wrapper for dompdf, so you can easily export a view as pdf.

Example of `css` to use for loading fonts:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
    }

    html, body {
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to change this plugin, may be its encoding problem